# Books on Prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, book-recommendation

I am a graduate student and have just finished Burton's book on number theory. Now I want to read further on prime numbers. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I second Martin's recommendation of Pomerance & Crandall.

On the popularizer level we have books like George P. Loweke's *The Lore of Prime Numbers* and David Wells's *Prime Numbers: The Most Mysterious Figures in Math*.

Somewhere in the middle is Ribenboim's *Little Book of Bigger Primes*.

On a more advanced level there are books like Fine & Rosenberger's *Number Theory: An Introduction Via the Distribution of Primes* and David Cox's *Primes of the Form $x^2 + ny^2$: From Fermat, Class Field Theory, and Complex Multiplication*. That one might be a little difficult to search for in your library's computerized catalog, plus it assumes a lot of knowledge of advanced algebra.

By the way, these are all books I have checked out from a library at one time or another. If I were you, I'd just casually browse in the vicinity of `QA 240` in your university's library and `510` in your public library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion Albert, but the library of our town does not have this kind of books and when I searched in my college library I got nothing in this topic.

Answer (score 6):

- [The New Book of Prime Number Records](http://www.amazon.in/Prime-Number-Records-Computers-Medicine/dp/0387944575/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1440713916&sr=8-12&keywords=Prime+Number) by Paulo Ribenboim is very good and will most likely fit best to your need.
- [Prime Obsession: Bernhard Riemann and the Greatest Unsolved Problem in Mathematics](http://www.amazon.in/Prime-Obsession-Bernhard-Greatest-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B004D39PGU/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1440713916&sr=8-5&keywords=Prime+Number) by John Derbyshire. I am currently reading this book and it is a great book which tried to explain Riemann hypothesis to a layman (with basic high school math, not even calculus) and succeeds on some level too. On the other hand it explains the connection of Riemann Hypothesis with prime numbers. Also, a great historic chapters and insights into **Prime Obsession** in history of Maths.

Answer (score 5):

You could try Carl Pomerance *Prime numbers, a computational Perspective*.

Answer (score 5):

Marcus du sautoy *Music of the primes* provides a good history and is more recreational (ie no proper theorems or proofs) but does get more technical than your average public maths book.

Comment: I'd recommend books by Paulo Ribenboim: among which *My numbers, my friends*, *The little book of big primes*.

Comment: I just thought that since OP was a graduate they might prefer something which used slightly more technical language, but even I enjoy reading stuff at a basic level if its new to me.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend *Elementary Number Theory: An Algebraic Approach* by Mr. Ethan Bolker. The author is sometimes active on this very site.

In general, any book about elementary number theory is sure to contain lots of theorems and proofs about prime numbers. Algebraic number theory books, too.

The book about $\sqrt{2}$ might also have some interesting material about prime numbers.

Answer (score 3):

There is a wonderful book that just came out:
An *Illustrated Theory of Numbers* by Martin Weissman

It is a very interesting read and provides lots of visualizations from number theory.

Comment: plz answer :   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3611104/divisibility-of-coefficient-related-to-cyclotomic-integer