# Divisibility of Coefficient Related to Cyclotomic Integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, cyclotomic-polynomials

[In this blog,](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/08/kummers-proof-for-regular-primes-case.html) I found the following lemma-

Lemma 4: Coefficients of corresponding powers of $(α - 1)$ must be congruent mod $λ$ provided all powers are less than the $(λ - 1)$ st.

if:

$a_0 + a_1(α - 1) + a_2(α-1)^2 + ... + a_{λ-2}(α-1)^{λ-2} ≡ b_0 + b_1(α - 1) + b_2(α-1)^2 + ... + b_{λ-2}(α-1)^{λ-2} (\mod λ)$

then:

$a_0 ≡ b_0 (\mod λ)$

$a_1 ≡ b_1 (\mod λ)$

...

$a_{λ-2} ≡ b_{λ-2} (\mod λ)$

Proof:

(1) If $a_0 + a_1(α - 1) + ... + a_{λ-2}(α - 1)^{λ-2} ≡ $
$b_0 + b_1(α -1) + ... + b_{λ-2}(α-1)^{λ-2} (\mod (α - 1)^{λ-1}$, then:

$c_0 + c_1(α-1) + ... ≡ 0 (\mod (α - 1)^{λ-1})$   where $c_i = a_i - bi$

(2) Then $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod α - 1)$ which also gives us that $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod λ)$

(3) Then $c_1(α-1) ≡ 0 (\mod (α-1)^2)$ so that $(α-1)$ divides $c_1$ which means that $c_1 ≡ 0 (\mod λ)$.

(4) We can use the same logic to show that all $c_i ≡ 0 (\mod λ)$

(5) So, $a_i - b_i = 0$, this implies that $a_i = b_i$

**I couldn't understand the second line-**

> (2) Then $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod α - 1)$ which also gives us that $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod λ)$

**How it is derived that  $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod α - 1)$ and how it implies   $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod λ)$ ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your question.  It has been 14 years since I wrote that blog post.

I was using the blog to take notes on this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387902309) by [Harold Edwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Edwards_(mathematician)).

Here's the argument:

(1)  From Step 1:

$$c_0 + c_1(α-1) + \dots + c_{\lambda-2}(α-1)^{\lambda-2} \equiv 0 \pmod { (α - 1)^{λ-1} } \text{ where } c_i = a_i - b_i$$

(2) Since $(α-1)$ divides $(α-1)^{\lambda-2}$, it follows that:

$$c_0 + c_1(α-1) + \dots + c_{\lambda-2}(α-1)^{\lambda-2} \equiv 0 \pmod { (α - 1) }$$

(3)  This wouldn't be true if $c_0 \not\equiv 0 \pmod {\alpha - 1}$ so we can conclude that $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {\alpha - 1}$

(4) From Corollary 3.2, [here](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/08/ideal-numbers-1.html), it follows that:

$$ (α - 1)^{λ-1} = λ \times \text{ unit}$$

(5)  Since $\lambda$ divides $(α - 1)^{λ-1}$, it follows that:

$$c_0 + c_1(α-1) + \dots + c_{\lambda-2}(α-1)^{\lambda-2} \equiv 0 \pmod { \lambda }$$

Comment: I understand  $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {\alpha - 1}$ but from $ (α - 1)^{λ-1} = λ \times \text{ unit}$ how can we write  $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod { λ }$? because $ (α - 1)^{λ-1} = λ \times \text{ unit}$,  not $ (α - 1)= λ \times \text{ unit}$, plz explain.

Comment: It comes from step(1).  Since $C(\alpha) \equiv 0 \pmod {(\alpha - 1)^{\lambda-1}}$, it follows that $(\alpha-1)^{\lambda - 1}$ divides $C(\alpha)$.  Since $\lambda$ divides $(\alpha-1)^{\lambda-1}$, it follows that $\lambda$ likewise divides $C(\alpha)$

Comment: Is $C(\alpha)= c_0 + c_1(α-1) + \dots + c_{\lambda-2}(α-1)^{\lambda-2}$? in this case, it is clear that $C(\alpha) \equiv 0 \pmod {(\alpha - 1)^{\lambda-1}}$, but my issue is  with a constant term $c_0$, to be precise, how we write $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {λ}$, it is not clear that $C(\alpha) \equiv 0 \pmod {λ}$ implies $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {λ}$, because $c_0$ is a constant term of the polynomial $C(\alpha)$ and so far we managed to prove, $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {\alpha - 1}$, note that you are proving $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {λ}$ from $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {\alpha - 1}$.

Comment: Also, Could tell where in your mentioned book I can found the proof of this lemma? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of $C(\alpha)$.  I see the problem.  The argument is NOT proving $c_0 \equiv 0\ \pmod {\lambda}$ from $c_0 \equiv 0 \pmod {\alpha - 1}$.  It is deriving it from step (1).  I was making two different conclusions at the same time (because the conclusions are similar).

Comment: Sorry, that would take me too much time.   I would have to find the book (if I still have it).  :-)

Comment: Okay but you explicitly wrote that "$c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod α - 1)$ which also gives us that $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod λ)$"... also, if we are proving  $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod λ)$ from step (1), why we need to show $c_0 ≡ 0 (\mod α - 1)$ ?

Comment: Fair point.  I will review the blog an update it.  To be clear, these were notes that I was taking from a book.  I was quite surprised when I found a lot of people were visiting.  :-)

Comment: In the post entitled "Kummer's Proof for Regular Primes: Case I", why we need step 9 and 10 in theorem, it seems redundant, could u plz revisit and comment? Link: http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2006/08/kummers-proof-for-regular-primes-case.html

Comment: I did the steps based on how I think.  Sometimes, conclusions were not obvious to me so I included additional steps to make it superclear.  If you look at the [original proof](https://books.google.com/books/about/Fermat_s_Last_Theorem.html?id=_IxN-5PW8asC) by Edwards, it is very terse and well-done.  This was my attempt to make it very easy to process.  The result is that most of my steps appear as overkill to professional mathematicians.  :-)

Comment: I don't have problems with "steps to make it superclear", but i don't see how those steps makes things more clear they seems to stuck at some point without completing the argument, we are trying to find a easier version of Kummer's Thm of regular prime, with detail proof, your blog seems to be the best option, but having these little issues.... anyway thanks.

Comment: If you post another question with any details that you feel are missing, I will be glad to work on it.  I've been thinking about doing a reboot on the blog.  I've gotten a bit better at math over the years.  :-)

Comment: Have You complied the content of blog on regular prime in a latex document in the way you have written the blog? I saw the book but it is not well organized as your book.

Comment: At that time, MathJax was not readily available.  I was actually doing Latex on Wikipedia's sandbox and then copying the image.  I organized the blog based on my interest which goes beyond Edwards.  I used different sources depending on the topic.